# When the code is ran on VS2010 in windows10 OS, application buttons are not visible. But the same code works fine in windows7 VS2010

Tags: vb.net

We have moved from Win 7 to Win 10 recently.
Visual Studio 2010 is installed on Win 10. Code build using .net framework v4.0. while running the code in local few buttons on the application are not visible when we run the code.
The same code is published then deployed on the server and ran, buttons are visible.
I have checked the IE compatibility, ran the application on different browser but still no result. tried to check the properties of the solution.

no error message occurred. only buttons not visible while running in local.

I have checked the IE compatibility, ran the application on different browser but still no result. tried to check the properties of the solution.

no error message occurred. only buttons not visible while running in local.

```
Public Shared Function ButtonVisibleCheck(ByVal Id As String, ByVal Num As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim retVal As Boolean = False
    Dim cmd As OracleCommand
    Dim SHOW_BUTTON_SQL As String = "DECLARE v_status BOOLEAN; BEGIN v_status := xx_pkg.button_show(:p_app_number,:p_page_number ,:p_button_id); if v_status THEN :p_return_val := 'Y'; ELSE :p_return_val := 'N'; END IF;  END;"

    Try
        cmd = New OracleCommand
        cmd.CommandText = SHOW_BUTTON_SQL
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("p_return_val", OracleType.VarChar, 1)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_app_number", ApplicationDAO.AppId).DbType = DbType.Int32
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_page_number", PageNumber).DbType = DbType.Int32
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("p_button_id", ButtonId).DbType = DbType.AnsiString

        OracleCommandProcessor.ExecuteNonQueryInContext(cmd)

        retVal = IIf(DbUtilities.Nvl(cmd.Parameters("p_return_val").Value, "N") = "Y", True, False)


    Catch ex As Exception
        retVal = "Error while processing Validation Check"
    Finally
        cmd = Nothing
    End Try

    Return retVal
End Function
```

`IIf(DbUtilities.Nvl(cmd.Parameters("p_return_val").Value, "N") = "Y", True, False)` In this line `"p_return_val").Value` is always coming as `Null` in  windows 10 . But in windows 7 it will return `Y`.

`IIf(DbUtil.Nvl(cmd.Parameters("p_return_val").Value, "N") = "Y", True, False)` In this line `"p_return_val").Value` is always coming as `Null` in  windows 10 . But in windows 7 it will return `Y`and based on that we are displaying button visible true or False.

Comment: Try this `oraclecommand.bindbyname = true`. I feel your parameters are out of order. BTW, is this `system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand` or ODP?

Comment: This is system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand. BindbyName is not a member of system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.

Comment: Then move your first parameter into last position and see what it does. If you read MS documentation, they deprecating `system.data.oracleclient`. You should use ODP - `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess`.  MS said this for years. This could be your problem - that Microsoft has not update something for it to work on Win 10. `BindbyName` is a feature of ODP. Also, don't use `IIF`, use `If( , , )` . Especially in this case, you only wasting computing power. Do `retVal = DbUtilities.Nvl(cmd.Parameters("p_return_val").Value, "N") = "Y"`